# What is causing this segmentation fault in string concatenation?

Tags: c, string, string-literals, strcat

I am doing an exercise in C to brush myself up on the topic. I am trying to use my program to manipulate header files; but the program returns "Segmentation fault". I have isolated the issue to the following segment of code. Can any one help me see what exactly is wrong with it ?

```
    header=strtok(st,"\"");
    header=strtok(NULL,"\"");
    f=fopen(header,"r");
    if(f)
    {
            while((ch=fgetc(f))!=EOF)
            fputc(ch,f2);

            fclose(f);
    }
    else
    {
            header2=(char *)malloc(strlen("/usr/include")+strlen(header));
            header2=strcat("/usr/include/",header);
            f=fopen(header2,"r");

            printf("%s\n",header2);

            while((ch=fgetc(f))!=EOF)
            fputc(ch,f2);

            fclose(f);
   }
```

I have noted that the issue occurs only when I am trying to access the /usr/include/ location. Some sort of authentication issue ? If so, how to over come it ? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You can't do this: `header2=strcat("/usr/include/",header);`. The first parameter has to be the destination buffer.

Comment: Check the result `header` from `strtok` before using it.

Comment: After all the other problems are fixed, you'll still need to check the return value from the second `fopen`.

Comment: You are not opening `f2`, but re-opening `f` with a different file name (without closing the first opening).

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a string literal as the target of `strcat` -- string literals are not modifiable, and it doesn't have enough space to hold the concatenated string. A better way to combine the variable with a prefix is with `sprintf`.

```
header2 = malloc(strlen("/usr/include/")+strlen(header)+1);
sprintf(header2, "/usr/include/%s", header);
```

Note that you need to add 1 to the combined lengths when calling `malloc()`, to allow space for the trailing null byte.

You could also use `strcpy` followed by `strcat`:

```
strcpy(header2, "/usr/include/");
strcat(header2, header);
```

Comment: `sprintf` is like `printf`, but it puts the result in a string instead of printing it.

Answer (score 2):

The major problem is in

```
header2=strcat("/usr/include/",header);
```

as you're supplying a [string literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) as the *destination*. This does not have any space to hold the concatenated string. So, you're essentially trying to access invalid memory which  invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, for [`strcat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat), the behavior is, (*emphasis mine*)

> The `strcat()` function appends the `src` string to the `dest` string, **overwriting the terminating null byte** (`'\0'`) at the end of `dest`, [...]

which, in your case, involves an attempt to modify a string literal, which again, invokes UB.

Then, there are more to point out, like

- `strlen()` does not count the terminating null-byte for a *string*, so using `strlen()` for allocating memory should contain a `+1` as the size to get the space for the null-termination.
- [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).
- Always check the return value of library calls like `fopen()` for success before using the return value.

Comment: string literals also aren't modifiable.

Comment: @Barmar Right, that's also a valid point, connsidered the null-substitution, let me add.